# What does the banner of Ba'alzamon look like?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Eye of the World*, the first novel in The Wheel of Time saga, Robert Jordan, the author wrote:

> at night their cookfires outnumbered the stars and dawn revealed the banner of Ba'alzamon at their head. Ba'alzamon. Heart of the dark. An ancient name of the Father of Lies.

I don't recall him describing the banner. Does he describe it at some point?

Comment: I don't think it is described. However, I did a bit of research and the trolloc page from WoT wiki claims there should be a reference to a trolloc banner "a man-shape wrapped in flames" in _The Dragon Reborn_, Chapter 36. I read the whole chapter (in a translated version) and didn't find any such reference there, though Ba'alzamon makes an appearance in it. Maybe someone who got the original English version can check out this chapter, see if something was lost in translation? Or the wiki could just be wrong, of course.

Comment: @Amarth I think you have the wrong reference, Wiki appears to cite that as coming from _Knife of Dreams_ Chapter 19. I don't have a copy handy, but go see if you can find it now :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe Ah, indeed. I found the reference now and I got Knife of Dreams in English. This is during an attack of a Tear estate where Rand is staying. This is the battle where they recall how to make deathgates for the first time. These trollocs are not sent by Ba'alzamon I think.